# CodeIgniter - generate a code based on a string that a user enters

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day,

I am trying to generate a code based on a string that a user enters.
The code should be unique and will be checked in the database if its already used.

For example if the user enters "The Code Snippet", the code should be "TCS" by default, if already taken, it should be something like "THECS" and so on until a code is found that is not used.

I am using CodeIgniter, but any PHP function will work.

My current code is as follows:

```
$trimmed_schoolname = trim($school_name);
    $org_array = explode(" ",$trimmed_schoolname);

    $disallowed_words = array('and', 'of', 'or');
    $name_words = array_diff($org_array, $disallowed_words);

    if (count($name_words) == 1)
    {
        $recommended_code = substr($trimmed_schoolname, 0, 3);

        if ($this->check_if_used($recommended_code,$domain_ext))
        {               
            if ($this->check_if_used($recommended_code,$domain_ext))
            {
                $recommended_code = substr($trimmed_schoolname, 0, 4);
            }
            if ($this->check_if_used($recommended_code,$domain_ext))
            {
                $recommended_code = substr($trimmed_schoolname, 0, 5);
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (count($name_words) == 2)
    {
        $recommended_code = substr($name_words[0], 0, 1).substr($name_words[1], 0, 1);

        if ($this->check_if_used($recommended_code,$domain_ext))
        {               
            if ($this->check_if_used($recommended_code,$domain_ext))
            {
                $recommended_code = substr($name_words[0], 0, 2).substr($name_words[1], 0, 1);
            }
            if ($this->check_if_used($recommended_code,$domain_ext))
            {

                $recommended_code = $name_words[0].substr($name_words[1], 0, 2);
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (count($name_words) > 2) 
    {
        foreach ($name_words as $word)
        {
            $recommended_code .= substr($word, 0, 1);
        }   

        if ($this->check_if_used($recommended_code,$domain_ext))
        {
            $recommended_code = ''; 
            $recommended_code .= $name_words[0];
        }

        if ($this->check_if_used($recommended_code,$domain_ext))
        {
            $recommended_code = ''; 
            $recommended_code .= $name_words[0];

            $i = 1;

            while ($i < count($name_words))
            {
                $recommended_code .= substr($name_words[$i], 0, 1);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The above is probably a very big way of doing it, so any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not simplify it massively and use something like the first n characters of the input text and an appended ID number at the end of that, so something like `thecod0001`?

Comment: Could work, but the code will we used to log into the users account with URL tcs.website.com, so its more about being easy for the user to remember and for others to identify the company, as other normal users will also use this to join the company or to get to their website on the specified URL

Comment: I know this is straying way out of scope of your question, but if you need this code to be easily remembered, and if it's going to be used frequently, why not just let the user choose it? You can then just check if it already exists and notify them in case it does.

Comment: The option is there, but this will be like a recommended/default code that the user can use if they do not want to enter their own. We are trying to make a registration page where the user has to do the least amount of work

Comment: Use something like `strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', trim($school_name))` to make the default start point. Check if that is unique. If not, add a random 3 or 4 digit number to the end and then allow the user the opportunity to change the whole thing if they don't like it.

Comment: think I will be sticking with @user2959229 last comment, looks like my best option at the moment and the closest to what I needed, so you can write an answer so the question can be andwered :)

Comment: @RickusHarmse - Answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like `strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', trim($school_name))` to make the default start point. Check if that is unique. If not, add a random 3 or 4 digit number to the end and then allow the user the opportunity to change the whole thing if they don't like it.

If the example input name is something like "The Code Snippet", the first option to check would be `thecodesnippet`. If that is not unique, then try `thecodesnippet123`, or even `thecodesnippet1` or `thecodesnippet2`. Alternatively let them customize it and then check their input.